# What is the meaning of the semicolon in $h(x;\theta)$?

Tags: notation, machine-learning

The context is machine learning, and the full expression is $h(x;\theta) = \operatorname{sign}(\theta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \theta_d x_d)$. $x$ is a feature vector and $\theta$ parameterizes a set of classifiers. I don't understand why the semicolon was used instead of the comma I would expect. Does it add meaning to the definition of $h$?

Comment: Is $h$ supposed to be a probability density function or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just like a comma. A semicolon is used sometimes to emphasize the fact that different variables play different roles. In your example, the xs are felt like normal variables while the thetas are more like parameters to the function.

Comment: Might be worth saying we usually have something of the form $x \sim h(\theta)$ to specify the model and then $h(x;\theta)$ to denote the specific value of the likelihood of the data point $x$ in the model.