# What does a conditional gaussian distribution say about the random variables themselves?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I have a few questions on conditional Gaussian distributions that I'm hoping to get some clarity on.

Let $P_{X|Y}(x|y) = N(x\:;y\:, 1)$

1. Can we deduce anything about *X* and *Y* with no further information?
2. Is this equivalent to saying $X|Y = Y + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed?

The reason that I have these questions is that I'm reading literature which incorporates a Markov chain for a series of timesteps. It is stated that $P(\textbf{x}_t | \textbf{x}_{t-1}) \sim N(\:\textbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbb{I}\:)$, and all of the literature refers to each timestep as "adding Gaussian noise" to the previous one.

In general, In understand how this can be *viewed* as adding noise to the previous timestep because we are centering our conditional distribution on the value of the previous timestep and can therefore expect to be close to the previous timestep, but **I don't see how we can guarantee that this noise is Gaussian**.

Does anyone have insight as to what I am missing? Or are the papers I am reading not 100% accurate. I should note that these papers are not in pure math but in machine learning, so I don't think it would be completely out of the question that there is a misphrasing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly mean $P(X|Y)$?

Comment: @Masacroso the conditional distribution of X given Y

Comment: but this is not a random variable, its a kernel (a family of measures), so its strange to assert that it have a distribution. This is why I asked my previous question, its not so clear what the expression $P(X|Y)\sim N(0,1)$ means

Comment: @Masacroso I edited for clarification. $P(X|Y=y) \sim N(x\:;y\:, 1)$ means that the conditional distribution of X given a random variable Y (whose distribution is unknown) is a normal distribution centered at the value of the random variable having unit variance.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of $x$ in $N(x;y,1)$.

Comment: @FdA Looks like I made a notational mistake https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799804/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-semicolon-in-hx-theta.

Comment: There are some notational issues here, but if you are saying $X \sim N(Y,1)$ then this is equivalent to $X=Y + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ independent of $Y$; you have $\epsilon=X-Y$.  You can then make some obvious points  such as $E[X]=E[Y]$ and $Var(X)=Var(Y)+1\ge 1$ if those exist and that  $X$ has support on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Henry Thank you! This is true for an arbitrary distribution Y? Do you have a resource I can look at to see why this is the case?

In particular, the paper claims that $p(x_t|x_{t-1}) := N(x_t; x_{t-1}, \mathbb{I})$ is equivalent to saying that $x_t$ is equal to $x_{t-1}$ plus the addition of some Gaussian noise. It seems like this is indeed true from your comment, and I'm hoping to better understand why.

Thank you!

Comment: @Henry I'm going to open another question and delete this one because I now have better focus of what I need to ask. I will wait for a bit in case you have any final comments. Thanks again!